# Sort list of dictionaries in such a way that specific dict's value should placed first

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Here is the sample of list of dictionaries:

```
controllers = [{'is_reboot_required': 'optional', 'raid_controller': 'RAID.Integrated.1-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.3-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.6-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.7-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'false', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.8-1'}]
```

I need to generate output in such a way that:

- List of dictionaries in which the dictionary who's key has `is_reboot_required`:
- `'true'` should be placed first.

Like Below:

```
[{'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.7-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.6-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.3-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'optional', 'raid_controller': 'RAID.Integrated.1-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'false', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.8-1'}]
```

I already tried this, and it worked, but it's just not an efficient way to accomplish this. It would be helpful if someone could give me better solution which is more time-wise efficient.

Code which I tried:

```
final_controllers=[]
for controller in controllers:
    for key,value in controller.items():
        if value == "true":
            if controller not in final_controllers:
                final_controllers.insert(0, controller)
        else:
            if controller not in final_controllers:
                final_controllers.append(controller)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @MrGeek's answer works, it is not very efficient since it uses the `sorted` function, which costs *O(n log n)* in average time complexity.

The main reason your code is not efficient is because it costs *O(n)* in time complexity to insert an item at the start of a list, and you're doing it for every iteration of the loop when the value of the `is_reboot_required` key is `true`, resulting in *O(n ^ 2)* in worst-case time complexity.

You can use `collections.deque` instead of a list so that an insertion at both ends of the sequence costs just *O(1)* in time complexity, resulting in an overall  *O(n)* in time complexity:

```
from collections import deque

final_controllers = deque()
for controller in controllers:
    if controller['is_reboot_required'] == 'true':
        final_controllers.appendleft(controller)
    else:
        final_controllers.append(controller)
```

so that `list(final_controllers)` becomes:

```
[{'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.7-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.6-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.3-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'optional', 'raid_controller': 'RAID.Integrated.1-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'false', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.8-1'}]
```

Comment: Yess.This is what i was looking for.! Thank you very much for in-detailed explanation. Appreciate your help..!

Answer (score 4):

The following `lambda` key function will suffice (using the built-in `sorted` function). This works because `True > False`:

```
final_controllers = sorted(controllers, key = lambda x : x['is_reboot_required'] != 'true')
```

Output:

```
>>> print(*final_controllers, sep='\n')

{'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.3-1'}
{'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.6-1'}
{'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.7-1'}
{'is_reboot_required': 'optional', 'raid_controller': 'RAID.Integrated.1-1'}
{'is_reboot_required': 'false', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.8-1'}
```

Comment: The reason i didn't accept this as an answer is because i might have scenario in which key inside dictionary may not be present while iterating list of dictionaries. Otherwise it's awesome one-liner . +1

Answer (score 1):

Create a `dict` containing the order of the values. If there are more values add them to the `dict` to make it work.

```py
controllers = [
    {'is_reboot_required': 'optional', 'raid_controller': 'RAID.Integrated.1-1'},
    {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.3-1'},
    {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.6-1'},
    {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.7-1'},
    {'is_reboot_required': 'false', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.8-1'}
]

order = {'true': 0, 'optional': 1, 'false': 2}
controllers.sort(key=lambda d: order[d['is_reboot_required']])

pprint(controllers)
```

Output:

```py
[{'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.3-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.6-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'true', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.7-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'optional', 'raid_controller': 'RAID.Integrated.1-1'},
 {'is_reboot_required': 'false', 'raid_controller': 'AHCI.Slot.8-1'}]
```